# Git SSH won't connect on custom port

Tags: windows, git, powershell, ssh, git-bash

I'm running on a Windows 7 machine with msysgit, git Bash, tortoisegit and posh-git all installed.

Our company has a git server that previously ran on https. Then, for a time it had both https and ssh. Now it has only ssh. Everything ran without issues on https.

I generated and installed all my keys without a problem. I can push/pull/whatever via tortoisegit with no problems. However, I can no longer use the command line in either git BASH or powershell + posh-git. I think part of the reason is because we do not use port 22, but a custom port for increased security.

Note that hostname and port number have been changed in the commands below to protect the innocent.

I get the errors below when trying to push/pull, but I'm showing commands just to test the ssh server to show that ssh is the issue (I believe). If I don't specify the port, it finds the server and attempts to connect - but since it defaults to port 22 I get an error as shown below:

```
C:\gitpath\design [master]> ssh ssh://git@dev.zzz.us
ssh: connect to host dev.zzz.us port 22: Bad file number
```

If I do specify the port, however, it then cannot find the hostname:

```
C:\gitpath\design [master]> ssh ssh://git@dev.zzz.us:9092/
ssh.exe": Could not resolve hostname dev.zzz.us:9092/: no address associated with name
```

I've looked at similar posts and they all pointed to needing the protocol included (ssh://) to prevent this error. As you can see, I'm getting this error even with the protocol in place. I've also tried with and without the ending '/' - same result. Is there something else with the syntax I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifiers such as `ssh://git@dev.zzz.us:9092/` can be used by git to specify
a non-standard port for SSH when configuring remote repositories. However, the
remote identifier must include the path (I prefer to use the absolute path) to
the remote repository, e.g.,

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@dev.zzz.us:9092/path/to/repo.git
```

However, to test such a connection using the `ssh` command, you use the `-p`
option to specify the TCP port number and then `user@hostname`:

```
ssh -p 9092 git@dev.zzz.us
```

Note: I usually use Git from a Unix system (not from Windows) and the `ssh`
command is provided by the *Openssh* package.

**Edit**: I just checked on a Windows box and see that MSysGit also uses Openssh
so the above commands work; I haven't checked with Powershell but there shouldn't
be any issues running the above commands through the Bash shell.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple I wasn't quite getting. I didn't configure the new repo right and my test method was flawed. Both ssh -p and git add|fetch|push|pull are working.

Comment: Glad to have been able to help. Your question provided plenty of relevant context so I thought it was worth answering. That reminds me that I should upvote the question since it contained just the relevant information.